# setting environment vairables when pip install my_wheel

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables, setup.py, python-wheel

I am wondering if there is a way to set environment variables when I use pip to install python wheel I built.

Can I wirte something in setup.py to get this:

`pip install wheel_0_I_built` == `pip install wheel_1_I_built` + `export MY_ENV=var`

where wheel_0_I_built and wheel_1_I_built have same function but wheel_0_I_built sets environment variable when being installed.

Thanks

Comment: Put it infront of the command, not at the end.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean. Could you please add more instructions ?

Comment: `MY_ENV=var pip install wheel_0_I_built `. In any case you just have to place the first part infront of the command you are running (manually). Adding it to a script or setup.py is not recommended.

Comment: For some reason, I can't set environment variables directly by ```export MY_ENV=var```. Is there any other ways? Thanks